# How to logout from app using symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I have a question, I'm new in symfony2 and I tried to create a small system with login and logout. The problem is that in my debug bar after logout I get : Logged in as anon, Authenticated Yes, Token class Anonymous Token.
My controller :

```
class UserController extends Controller{
public function loginPageAction(){
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage.html.twig');
}
public function loginCheckAction(Request $request){
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
    $login    = $request->request->get('username');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('ShopDesktopBundle:Customer');
    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('customer_login'=> $login, 'customer_password'=> $password));
    if($user){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('shop_desktop_homepage'));
    }else{
        return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage.html.twig',array('message_failed' => 'Eroare : login sau password este gresit'));
    }
}
public function logoutAction(){
    $session =$this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->clear();
}
```

} 
My login view :

```
<form action="{{ path('shop_login_user') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Autentificare</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

In layout, my logout button :

```
<span><a href="{{ path('shop_logout_user') }}" style="color: #ffffff;">Logout</a></span>
```

My security.yml:

```
security:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

# the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
# for specific sections of your app
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: shop_login_user
            login_path: shop_show_login_page
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous: true
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

# with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
# of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

File with routes :

```
shop_show_login_page:
path: /login
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage }

shop_login_user:
path: /loginUser
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginCheck }

shop_logout_user:
path: /logout
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:logout }
```

So, the problem is that the logout button doesn't work because in debug bar symfony I authentificated as anonymous. Is that a good system of login/logout?
Please help me please. Thx in advance ! ! !

Comment: you know, i don't recall having to write a logout function at all when setting up a standard symfony logout.  What happens when you remove the defaults for shop_logout_user in your routing.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Use `shop_logout_user` as path in your security.yml file :

```
    logout:
        invalidate_session: true
        path:   shop_logout_user
        target: /
```

This route does not need a controller, so in your routing.yml file you only need to do :

```
shop_logout_user:
  path: /logout
```

Then, your user should be logged out when you redirect to this route. If not, check if you dont override the response kernel event, last time I had issue with logout it was because of this.

Comment: I tried but not work... I authentificated as anonim in status bar :(

Comment: Being authenticated as anonym means that you are disconnected ;)